# Transmission and curlftpfs: Operation not supported

Tags: mount, ftp, transmission, curlftpfs

I have an FTP server mounted with curlftpfs. But when I try to download torrent with Transmission to the mounted folder it gives me an error: `"torrent name" tr_fdFileCheckout failed for "file path" Operation not supported (inout.c:101)`
Transmission-daemon has root permissions, folder is mounted by root.

Comment: This isn’t a permissions issue but instead a file system issue. The way torrents work is fundamentally incompatible with things like `curlftpfs`.

Comment: So there is no way to use ftp server for torrents?

Comment: There is no *easy* way to use a `curlftpfs` file system with torrents in the manner you've specified, no. If you really must do things like this, it would make much more sense to download the torrent to an `ext4` device, then have Transmission write the file to the `curlftpfs` location after it's complete. However, there are a bunch of caveats that you'll need to consider when doing this, as you're going to be using a boatload of bandwidth with your setup.